# php javascript alertbox have to click 2 times before it show

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm doing php that is textbox a value empty it will open a alertbox (I'm using javascript in here )

this is my code

```
    <?php 
    include('config.php');

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $username=$_POST['username'];

    ?>

    <script>
        function validate(){
        if(document.forms[0].username.value==""){
          window.alert("You must enter both values");
          return false;
        }
        }
    </script>

    <?php
    }
    ?>



<html>
<div><p>Member Profile</p>
    <form action="testing.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validate();">
    Username<br>
    <input class="user" type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br>


<input type="submit" name="submit" value="register" />
</form>
</div>

</html>
```

The problem is i have to click 2 times before the alert show

please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the script is inside the php `if(isset){}` block, one click submits the form, which generates the script and then it works the second time.. try this setup instead:

```
<?php
    include ('config.php');

    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function validate () {
                if (document.forms[0].username.value == "") {
                    window.alert("You must enter both values");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p>
                Member Profile
            </p>
            <form action="testing.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validate();">
                Username
                <br>
                <input class="user" type="text" name="username" id="username" />
                <br>

                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="register" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Edit:

I've moved the script tag inside the head tag. I'm not sure if there are any implications for having the script outside but just to be sure I've moved it.

2nd Edit: (OCD is kicking in)

I've added body tags, not sure if you copied and pasted this code but it looked weird to me :)